# GParted is Frozen

Tags: partition, gparted

I've been trying to allocate more space for Windows... And to do that, I have to resize my Linux partition partition.

So I booted up from my flash drive and started up `gParted`. Everything was working great until `gParted` started to resize my Linux partition. It's been stuck at `6.33GB of 86.5GB copied` for about half an hour now. The entire OS has stopped responding and the flash drive is flashing like it does when it's active.

I have Linux Mint 11 on my flash drive.

I'm not too particularly worried about losing my data. I have it all backed up, but it would be nice if this could be recovered. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If it's hung, then it's hung... time to cut power and restore from backup.